# LLDB COMMAND : 'fr v var' vs 'p var'

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm new to LLDB and try to familiar those commands in the [official website](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html).
I'm confusing about the function of `fr v bar` and `p bar`.
As you can see from the website, they are described to 'Show the contents of local variable "bar"' and put in the same place.
But When I put them into real use in **Xcode 4.6.4**, there is some differences?

```
(lldb) fr v self
(FGPLoginViewController *const) self = 0x07566350
(lldb) p self
(FGPLoginViewController *) $0 = 0x07566350
(lldb) fr v self.initCount
error: "self" is a pointer and . was used to attempt to access "initCount". Did you mean    "self->initCount"?
(lldb) p self.initCount
(NSInteger) $1 = 0
```

initCount is a NSInteger property of FGPLoginViewController.
And my questions is what's the real differences between `fr v bar` and `p bar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference (as I understand it) is that `frame variable` is only for printing the
contents of *variables*, whereas `print` is a shortcut for 
`expression --` and can evaluate arbitrary C and Objective-C *expressions*.

In your example, `self.initCount` is the property syntax for `[self initCount]`. To evaluate that expression, the debugger compiles it and executes the code in the context of the
application.

Another example: `p 2+3` computes the sum and prints the result, but `fr v 2+3` gives
an error message.

On the other hand, `frame variable` has much more options to display variables.
For example, `fr v -r "app.*"` shows all variables starting with "app". You cannot do that
with the `print` command.

To summarize: `frame variable` is for variables and `print` (or `expr`) is for expressions.
In the case of *one variable* they both work equally well.

Comment: So `p`'s functions cover `fr v`'s and LLDB created `fr v` just to make it  clearer and more specified?

Comment: @nekoP: I have updated the answer and tried to explain it better.

Comment: Good answer Martin. There's also `target variable` -- `frame variable` will display local vars or arguments but if you want to view a global/file static, you need to use `ta v`. `print` doesn't make the distinction. Part of the overlap comes from early in lldb's development when `expr` was a work-in-progress and wasn't always usable - one could fall back on `fr v` in those instances. `fr v` has some simplistic knowledge of C syntax (I think you can say `fr v a->b->c` to follow a chain of pointers) but `expr` is actually handled by clang and compiled as Objective-C++; arbitrary code is allowed.

Comment: @JasonMolenda: Thank you very much! - But now I have one question to the master of [lldb] (-: If `target variable` prints global variables, what does `frame variable -g` do?

Comment: `fr v -g` displays global/statics for the compilation unit you're stopped in (default: display all of them, optionally display the ones you've specified).  `ta v` without a variable name does the same.  But `ta v` with the name of a global/static in another compilation unit will display that cu's global.  Example: I'm stopped in `a.c`, which defines global var `bar`.  `ta v`, `ta v bar`, `fr v -g` all display `bar`.  The file `b.c` defines `foo`.  `ta v foo` shows it.  `fr v -g foo` will not, `ta v` will not.  (`ta v` without an arg displays the *current* source file's globals/statics only.)

Comment: In my personal onbervations `fr v` is more stable, there some weird cases there `p`/`po` ceases to work, but `fr v` works just fine

Answer (score 1):

1.In LLDB, p is print and po is print object. 'p' is used to print non-pointer variables like bool, float etc. 
2.'fr v bar' means show the contents of the local variable(frame variable) bar.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, for the gdb aficionados out there, the `print` command does pretty much what the gdb `print` command did.  The `frame variable --no-locals` command is equivalent to gdb's `info args`, `frame variable --no-args` is equivalent to `info locals`, and `target variable` does what `info variables` did.

Jason is correct about the history, but these commands are also useful, for instance, in breakpoint commands where you want to print all the locals or args every time you stop.  Writing print expressions for all of them would be tedious, but `frame var` will give you all of them at one blow.